# bootstrap popover not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, svg, popover

Trying to display a bootstrap popover on an svg. Managed to get it working in Safari and Firefox (haven't yet tested Chrome) but can't get it to work in IE - tried IE11.

The key to the popover is that it is instigated on a click of the svg and then dismissed by either clicking on the x in the title of the popover or any where else on screen.

I have set up a jsfiddle that shows what I am trying to achieve. IT just doesn't work in IE11.

```
<a id="testPopover" tabindex="0" class="popover_wrapper" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-container="body">
<svg width="310" height="110">
   <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg> 
</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sregorcinimod/ut56eowb/

Comment: Possibly an issue with `focus` in IE, I bet it works with `click` instead?

Comment: But click stops the x in the title from working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems as though using bootstrap v4 might solve this. Further testing in progress

Comment: there was a fix in v3.37 that resolved my issue. now using v4

Answer (score 0):

I would change the trigger to `click`, and then instead of `data-dismiss="popover"` (which doesn't do anything), I would do `data-dismiss="#testPopover"`, so you get a reference to the element that has the popover, then you can do:

```
 $("body").on("click", ".popover .close", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $($(this).data('dismiss')).popover('hide');
 })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ut56eowb/13/

Comment: That doesn't help with the fact that I require "The key to the popover is that it is instigated on a click of the svg and then dismissed by either clicking on the x in the title of the popover or any where else on screen.". Clicking anywhere else on the screen does nothing.